# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str "counting the string"

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.5

I'm trying to count the number of d or D which are consecutive in the entered string.

But it's not working with this code, and I don't know where I did a mistake.

Please solve this issue.

```
up = 0
down = 0
down_count = 0

test = input("Enter test cases: ")

for i in test:
    s = input("Enter the string: ")
    l = list(s)
    for c in l:
        if l[c] == 'u' or 'U':
            up += 1
        if l[c] == 'd' or 'D':
            down += 1
        down_count += 1

print(down_count)
```

error is :

```
Enter test cases: 1
Enter the string: duuuuuddddduuudddd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HAMEED/PycharmProjects/crayons/ada_and_crayons.py", line 11, in <module>
    if l[c] == 'u' or 'U':
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `if`s should be of the form `c == 'u' or c == "U'`...

Comment: Replace `l[c]` with just `c`.

Comment: thanks the error is gone but im getting number times i entered u's and d's but not how many times 'd' comes consecutively.
for example: 'uuudddduuudddd'
the answer should be 2.
as 'd' consecutively repeats two times in given string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You have enough superfluous commands in your code for you goal, so I threw them out.)

You wanted only to count the *groups of consecutive `d` (or `D`) letters*. One approach (not very Pythonic, but you are a beginner) is this:

You will increase `down_count` when the current letter is `d` (or `D`), but *only if the previous letter was NOT* `d` (or `D`).

So I introduced the new boolean (logical) variable `prev_d` for testing if previous character was `d` (or `D`). For every iteration I set this value (to `True` or `False`) as it will be used in the *next* iteration:

```py
down_count = 0
prev_d     = False                  # Starting with no previous 'd' (or 'D')

s = input("Enter the string: ")

for c in s:
    if c.lower() == 'd':
        if not prev_d:              # This is the same as "if prev_d == False:"
            down_count += 1
        prev_d = True               # For next iteration: the previous char WAS 'd' or 'D'
    else:
        prev_d = False              # For next iteration: the prev. char was NOT 'd' or 'D'

print(down_count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) You are awesome.

Comment: @zahidshameer - You're welcome. Please consider to accept this answer (click on the check mark) and/or upvote it (click on the upper triangular arrow) if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

A Python for loop is really a for-each. `c` is already the element in the list, not the index.

Also note that `or` doesn't work like that; you need to explicitly compare with the element each time.

```
for c in l:
    if c == 'u' or c == 'U':
        ...
```

Comment: thanks the error is gone but im getting number times i entered u's and d's but not how many times 'd' comes consecutively.
for example: 'uuudddduuudddd'
the answer should be 2.
as 'd' consecutively repeats two times in given string

Comment: But you don't seem to have written any code to do that.

Comment: can you tell me that?

Answer (score 0):

Btw, your code has more issues. Back to your question:

Replace this part of your code

```
    for c in l:
        if l[c] == 'u' or 'U':
            up += 1
        if l[c] == 'd' or 'D':
            down += 1
        down_count += 1
```

with this:

```
    for c in l:
        if c.lower() == 'u':
            up += 1
        if c.lower() == 'd':
            down += 1
        down_count += 1
```

---

The explanations:

1. `c` itself is a *character* (`for c in l:`, where `l` is a list of characters); it is NOT an index.
2. `c.lower()` converts the letter into small, so you need to compare it only with the small letter.

But - as I told you - you code has more issues.

Comment: Thank, you. I'm very new to programming. Want to practice some programs. Donno how to write that logic, to consecutive letters in a string. Can you help me in that?

Comment: @zahidshameer - I wrote a new answer, which resolves your goal.